# Get user location and store it into array

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-location

On button press i am trying to store user location into array but i think the problem is that i don’t get coordinates back in time so the program continues and it prints my message “There was a problem getting your location”. Is there a way to wait for this waypoint coordinates before continuing program execution.

View:

```
 @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

 var body: some View {
   VStack{
     Button("Add") { addWaypoint() }
    }

    func addWaypoint(){
        self.locationManager.getWaypointLocation()
            if let waypoint = self.locationManager.waypoint {
        //ViewModel function that stores data into array
                coordinatesViewModel.addWaypoint(lat: waypoint.coordinate.latitude, lon: waypoint.coordinate.longitude)
            } else {
                print("There was a problem getting your location")
            }
        }
```

LocationManager:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject{
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var waypoint: CLLocation?
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.delegate = self
    }
            
    func getWaypointLocation(){
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate{      
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {            
            guard let waypoint = locations.last  else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //print(waypoint)
                self.waypoint = waypoint
                self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Getting the location is an asynchronous call so it will not return a value directly. Your code is correctly handling this in the LocationManager an it store the result in a `@Published` property. What you need to do in the view is to read this property once it has been updated. One way could be to use `.onChange(of:)` for the property and add it to your array there. I would recommend reading up on `@Published` and how it works since it's a central part in working with data in SwiftUI

Comment: There are several misconceptions with your code, look for a tutorial such as a workout app tutorial the premise is very similar.